# App version on Google Play

Tags: google-play

Well we released an update for our app last month, that set the minSDK to 5.0.  We did this because we had a server side change that would break those on below 5.0.

Is there anyway to release another app on Google Play that would only be for user on below 5.0?

If we were to release the 5.0 and below version for a few days and then release the 5.0 and above.  Will the 5.0 and below user still see that "slightly newer" below 5.0 release?

Comment: In case it is a server side problem as you said, I don't think the play store has any way to help you with that, but in case it is a problem with the sdk itself, maybe it could help to use app bundle instead of apk

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is known as "multi-APK". See [this help page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks).

You have two options for making sure users get the right APK.

- the simplest to understand option is to set `maxSdkVersion` in the manifest of your pre-5.0 APK, and `minSdkVersion` in your manifest for the post 5.0 APK.
- another option to use version code. Google Play will always deliver the highest version code that is compatible with a user. So if you make sure your pre-5.0 APK always has a lower version code than your post-5.0 APK, then both types of users will get the correct APK.